# How to extract specific text from text file

Tags: python, python-2.7

Hello Stackoverflow community,

I have problem regarding my code that I am trying to retrieve some specific text from a text file, Which I am able to to do. But I am using the seek method to retrieve the data. But for that I am giving the starting position of the text and the end position of the text. Which gives me the exact output what I want. But some times the length of the retrieving text might be longer then my code doesn't retrieve the whole text. So how can I do that

I am using python2.7 and trying to retrieve the specific data from a text file

```py
file = open("C:\Users\This_PC\p4.txt", "r")
file.seek(645)
string = file.read(13 - 0)
print string
```

I am getting the out put as expected like `test_label123`. But when in the text file if the length of the text is longer like `test_label12345` then I am getting the output as `test_label123` which is wrong.

p4.txt content is mentioned below

```
# A Perforce Label Specification.
#
#  Label:       The label name.
#  Update:      The date this specification was last modified.
#  Access:      The date of the last 'labelsync' on this label.
#  Owner:       The user who created this label.
#  Description: A short description of the label (optional).
#  Options:     Label update options: [un]locked, [no]autoreload.
#  Revision:    Optional revision specification to make an automatic label.
#  ServerID:    If set, restricts access to the named server.
#  View:        Lines to select depot files for the label.
#
# Use 'p4 help label' to see more about label views.

Label:  test_label123

Owner:  This_PC

Description:
    Created by Auto12

Options:    unlocked noautoreload
```

Comment: Use forward slashes, or double back slashes.

Comment: Can you add also the content of `p4.txt`

Comment: @papanito I have added the content of p4.txt in my question please check that.

Comment: Why don't read the line and then use regexp to extract the label?
https://pythonexamples.org/python-regex-extract-find-all-the-numbers-in-string/

Comment: @papanito Can you please explain it more or give an example code for it.

Comment: Did it work? if yes, I would appreciate you accept my answer

Answer (score 0):

You may use [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html), so something similar to this

```
import re

file = open("test.txt", "r")
string = file.read()
m = re.search('(?<=Label:) {0,2}(\w+)', string)

print m.group(1)
```

You may need to tweak your regexp to properly read the second apperance and not the first one (`Label:       The label name.`)